# Can't drag and drop files from OS X Lion to Samba share

Tags: macos, network-shares, samba, drag-and-drop

I have an Ubuntu box running a Samba share that I use to share files in my network. Since upgrading my mac to Lion I am unable to just drag and drop files from my mac into the mounted drives to copy them over. There were no problems doing this previously. When I try, the file appears in the folder for second or two then disappears. There is no error message.

Copying from the terminal still works fine and I can save a text file from TextEdit without any problems. It's only drag and drop that causes issues. Any ideas?

Edit: Looks like the problem sorted itself out after a reset.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem. Copying a file in terminal, or saving from an application worked, but when drag'n'dropping the file was created and then it vanished.

I managed to solve it by<
"force user" directive, and I added "inherit permissions = yes" just to be sure.

Hope this helps